# Как отсортировать список List<> в JAVA?

Tags: java

Вот есть код, который выводит список объектов. Мне нужно что бы он при выводе сортировался по названию поля.

```
public List<AvTemplate> completeAvTemplates() throws PersistenceException {
        List<AvTemplate> result = dm.findAll(AvTemplate.class);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return dm.findAll(AvTemplate.class)
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(AvTemplate::getFieldName))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

где `getFieldName` - геттер на поле, по которому надо сортировать

Comment: На toList пишет ошибку идея: Error:(84, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable toList
  location: class java.util.stream.Collectors

Comment: А, все, поставил вот так toList() и все заработало, спасибо огромное!